# Aplicaciones de C# no me genera datos en la BBDD Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vscode

Buenas noches estimados!!

a continuación detallo el error.

Hay dos aplicaciones distintss en C# Visual Studio 2022, un script se le llama "Estacion remota", la estacion remota es la encargada de recibir y/o alojar todas las variables Temp. ambiente, Caudal BBA, Temperatura de funcionamiento, Horas de func. y Presion. Enviando estos valores hacia la Pc Local (Mas adelante detallada como "Servidor") mediante un enlace inalámbrico (simulado).

El problema puede venir aca, no me guarda los datos en la tabla VARIABLE, pero el error se refleja en le script del "Servidor"

Script Estacion remota:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net; //Agregado
using System.Net.Sockets; //Agregado... socket se le llama al par IP---Puerto  
using System.Threading; //Agregado
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //Agregado




namespace ERemota_cliente_v3
{
    class Program
    {
        struct E_Remota
        {
            //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
            public int T_AMBIENTE;
            public int CAUDAL;
            public int T_CARCAZA;
            public int Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO;
            public float PRESION;
            public DateTime HORA;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Conectar();
        }
        public static void Conectar()
        {
            //Completamos los datos de Ejemplo
            E_Remota variables;
            variables.T_AMBIENTE = 0; //declaro la varibles que se van a colocar                                            
            variables.CAUDAL = 0;      //en un la bd
            variables.T_CARCAZA = 0;
            variables.Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO = 0;
            variables.PRESION = 0;
            variables.HORA = DateTime.Now;
            IPEndPoint miDireccion = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3"), 19847);
            // Acá debemos poner la Ip del servidor, y el puerto de escucha del servidor
            while (true)
            {


            Enviodatos(ref variables.T_AMBIENTE, ref variables.CAUDAL, ref    variables.T_CARCAZA, ref variables.Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO, ref variables.PRESION, ref variables.HORA);



            // puse esa porque corrí las dos aplicaciones en la misma pc
            Socket miPrimerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                miPrimerSocket.Connect(miDireccion); // Conectamos
                Console.WriteLine("Conectado con exito");
                int SizeAEnviar = Marshal.SizeOf(variables);
                byte[] enviar = new byte[SizeAEnviar];
                IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(SizeAEnviar);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(variables, ptr, false);
                Marshal.Copy(ptr, enviar, 0, SizeAEnviar);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                miPrimerSocket.SendTo(enviar, miDireccion);
                miPrimerSocket.Close();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);//tiempo de muestreo 1000= 1s

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Falla de comunicación con Servidor");
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", error.ToString());
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("Presione cualquier tecla para terminar");
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static void Enviodatos(ref int T_AMBIENTE2, ref int CAUDAL2, ref int T_CARCAZA2, ref int Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO2, ref float PRESION2, ref DateTime HORA1)
        {
            //************************************************************
            //
            //Random Temperatura Ambiente 
            Random rdm = new Random(T_AMBIENTE2);
            T_AMBIENTE2 = rdm.Next(-20, 50);//hace un random @-20c° a 50c°

            //*************************************************************
            //
            //Random Caudal  
            Random rdm2 = new Random(CAUDAL2);
            CAUDAL2 = rdm2.Next(0, 3800);//hace un random @500 a 3800 l/Hs 

            //CAUDAL2= (float)((rdm2.NextDouble() * 3800)+500);
            //PRESION2 += (float)((random.NextDouble() * 9.5) + 0.5);
            //*************************************************************
            //
            //Random Temperatura Carcaza
            Random rdm3 = new Random(T_CARCAZA2);
            T_CARCAZA2 = rdm3.Next(70, 110);//hace un random @70C° a 110C° 
            //*************************************************************
            //Random Horas de Funcionamiento
            for (int Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO = 1; Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO <= 1; Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO2++) //ESTE FOR CUENTA DE A el valor que se encuentra despues de <=
            {
                Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO = Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO + 1;
            }
            //*************************************************************
            //
            //Random Temperatura Carcaza
            Random rdm4 = new Random((int)PRESION2);
            PRESION2 = (float)((rdm4.NextDouble() * 9.5) + 0.5); //hace un random @0.5 a 10psi 
                                                                 //*************************************************************
                                                                 // hora que pasa cada variable    
            HORA1 = DateTime.Now;
            //***********************************
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La otra aplicacion se le llama "Servidor" que el error se refleja aca, pero como dije al principio, PUEDE que sea el problema el script de "Estacion remota"

El servidor es el encargado de recibir las variables, los estados y los tiempos para ser alojados en las tablas de la DB.

Codigo del Servidor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net; //Agregado
using System.Net.Sockets; //Agregado
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //Agregado
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace server_v3
{
    class Program
{
    struct E_Remota
    {
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
        public int T_AMBIENTE;
        public int CAUDAL;
        public int T_CARCAZA;
        public int Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO;
        public float PRESION;
        public DateTime HORA;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Conectar(); //Llamar a función Conectar, es ajeno al tema
    }
    public static void Conectar()
    {
        IPEndPoint miDireccion = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 19847);
        while (true)
        {
            Socket miPrimerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            E_Remota ValoresRecibidos = new E_Remota();
            // paso 2 - creamos el socket
           // IPEndPoint miDireccion = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 19847);
            //paso 3 -IPAddress.Any significa que va a escuchar al cliente en toda la red
            try
            {
                // paso 4
                miPrimerSocket.Bind(miDireccion); // Asociamos el socket a miDireccion
                miPrimerSocket.Listen(1); // Lo ponemos a escucha
                Console.WriteLine("Escuchando...");
                Socket Escuchar = miPrimerSocket.Accept();
                //creamos el nuevo socket, para comenzar a trabajar con él
                //La aplicación queda en reposo hasta que el socket se conecte a el cliente
                //Una vez conectado, la aplicación sigue su camino
                Console.WriteLine("Conectado con exito");
                Console.WriteLine();
                int size_msg = Marshal.SizeOf(ValoresRecibidos);
                byte[] resp = new byte[size_msg];
                int k = Escuchar.Receive(resp);
                /*Aca ponemos todo lo que queramos hacer con el socket*/
                IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size_msg);
                Marshal.Copy(resp, 0, ptr, size_msg);
                ValoresRecibidos = (E_Remota)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(E_Remota)); // DatosDeLlegada.GetType());
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                miPrimerSocket.Close(); //Luego lo cerramos
                                        //Los datos recibidos fueron:
                Console.WriteLine("Valores Recibidos:");
                Console.WriteLine("T_AMBIENTE :{0}", ValoresRecibidos.T_AMBIENTE);
                Console.WriteLine("CAUDAL :{0}", ValoresRecibidos.CAUDAL);
                Console.WriteLine("T_CARCAZA :{0}", ValoresRecibidos.T_CARCAZA);
                Console.WriteLine("Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO :{0}", ValoresRecibidos.Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO);
                Console.WriteLine("PRESION :{0}", ValoresRecibidos.PRESION.ToString("0.00"));//formato de la coma hay que cambiarlo en region >configuracion adicional y colocar el punto como coma
                Console.WriteLine("HORA :{0}", ValoresRecibidos.HORA.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
                Console.WriteLine();
                //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);//dejo una linea libre
                //llamo a la funcion variables 

                VARIABLES(ValoresRecibidos.T_AMBIENTE, ValoresRecibidos.CAUDAL, ValoresRecibidos.T_CARCAZA, ValoresRecibidos.Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO, ValoresRecibidos.PRESION,ValoresRecibidos.HORA);

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", error.ToString());
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("Presione cualquier tecla para terminar");
            //Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
    static void VARIABLES(int T_AMBIENTE, int CAUDAL, int T_CARCAZA, int Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO, /* aca fue puesto Float */ float PRESION,DateTime dateTime)
    {
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=localhost ; database = TITP ; integrated security = true");
        //conexion.Open();
        ////Console.WriteLine("Se abrió la conexión con el servidor SQLServer y se seleccionó la base de datos");
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            ////    //return;// el return va despues de la conexion
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.Write("Falla conexion con VARIABLES");//LA FALLA SE PRODUCE CUANDO SE APAGA EL SERVIDOR
            //Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", VARIABLES.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
            return;
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Se abrió la conexión con el servidor SQLServer y se seleccionó la base de datos VARIABLES");
        string cadena = "insert into VARIABLES(T_AMBIENTE, CAUDAL, T_CARCAZA, Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO, PRESION, HORA) values(" + T_AMBIENTE + ",'" + CAUDAL + "','" + T_CARCAZA + "','" + Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO + "','" + PRESION.ToString("0.00") + "','" + dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "')"; // ,'" + GETDATE()" + "')";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");
        
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        comando.Dispose();
        conexion.Close();
        return;

        }
    }
}
```

Cuando doy "EJECUTAR" a los dos codigos, primero tengo que hacerlo con "Servidor" y luego con "Estacion remota".

Esto es lo que me aparece con la consola de comandos de "Servidor"

[image: Consola de comandos de SERVER al ejecutar]

Ahora se los escribo por acá:

```
Valores Recibidos:
T_AMBIENTE :23
CAUDAL :3283
T_CARCAZA :75
Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO :5
PRESION :4,57
HORA :2022-09-02 11:54:05

Se abrió la conexión con el servidor SQLServer y se seleccionó la base de datos VARIABLES
Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type varchar to float.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at server_v3.Program.VARIABLES(Int32 T_AMBIENTE, Int32 CAUDAL, Int32 T_CARCAZA, Int32 Hs_FUNCIONAMIENTO, Single PRESION, DateTime dateTime) in C:\Users\mauro\OneDrive\Desktop\SCADA_TPI_proyect\ERemota_y_Server_funciona\server_v3\Program.cs:line 111
   at server_v3.Program.Conectar() in C:\Users\mauro\OneDrive\Desktop\SCADA_TPI_proyect\ERemota_y_Server_funciona\server_v3\Program.cs:line 76
ClientConnectionId:f0c3a2af-086d-4d7a-8f98-4fc1092605d6
Error Number:8114,State:5,Class:16
Escuchando...
```

Espero que se haya entendido la duda, no se me escriben los valores en la base de datos porque debe ser por eso, por los errores que aparecen en el cmd de "servidor"

Ante cualquier duda, en la consola de comandos de "Estacion remota" solo aparece la leyenda de "Conectado con exito..."

Estas son las tablas en la BBDD

Tabla "VARIABLES" dentro de la BBDD TITP:

[image: Tabla Variables]

Tabla HIST_ALARMAS:

[image: Tabla HIST_ALARMAS]

Tabla ALARMAS:

[image: Tabla ALARMAS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto!

El problema estaba en:
Panel de control - region y reloj - Region - Conf. adicional - Poner "Simbolo decimal" con un . (Punto), y en "simbolo de separacion de" poner una , (coma)